# callback functions

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Man Im trying to understand callback functions. Ive been over many articles and posts here on SO. The explanations seem circular and I think Im actually getting farther from understanding lol. Ive used them apparently in javascript events, but its more a 'memorize these lines' than 'this is whats going on and why' sort of understanding.

So heres my understanding.

Say you have 2 objects, function p() and function k(). You pass function k to p(). p() can then access k's inner variables.

```
function p(x){
    alert(x.n);//5
}

function k(){
    this.n = 5;
}

p(k);
```

Embarrassing how long its taken me to get just this.

Comment: I think you might be confusing callbacks with closures

Comment: great... wtf is a closure... fml lol, srsly need to go to bed now

Comment: don't apologize, i have an IQ of 140, an expensive education, and have spent probably 60% of my waking hours on a computer, and I still don't comprehend them.  they seem..  so convoluted... why muck-up the **process** with what boils down to a wildly unpredictable error routine?  separate that shit. i hate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe an example will help?

```
// First, lets declare the function we're going to call
calledFunction = function (callback, arg) {
    callback(arg);
};
// Second, lets declare the callback function
callbackFunction = function (arg) {
    alert(arg);
};
// Next, lets do a function call!
calledFunction(callbackFunction, "HAI");
```

So, `calledFunction()`'s `callback` argument is `callbackFunction` but, if you notice, we aren't calling the function yet, we're passing a variable the contains the function, and its `arg` function is just something to `alert()`. When `calledFunction()` is executed it takes whatever was passed as the `callback` argument and calls it with `arg` as its first, and only, argument.

Helped?

**Edit:** This still works if you use `function foo() {}`-style declarations. (just in case; I don't know how fluent you are with JavaScript)

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. `this.n = 5;` in `k()` does not set its "inner variable", and `x.n` access the function object's `x` property, instead of its inner variable.
Try this:

`function p(x) { alert(new x().n); }`

Variable binding is an important programming concept.

I think this article helps. http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript

Comment: so when x() is called, (which is just k masquerading as x), n is still in scope. Is that the point?

Comment: @John yeah, just ran that, n is not defined

Comment: and the this keyword is the window object in both functions, even inside x()

Comment: I guess that site was wrong.
"JavaScript Scope : "Optimise" JavaScript code taking advantage of the fact a function can access all local variables in the scope of the caller."  http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmaintricks.html